# Resharper inserts wrong template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I don't understand why resharper Alt + Insert inserts not class, but it's template instead.

[image]

Any ideas, why?

Comment: I know that you can customize the rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ReSharper doesn't work for one solution, try to clean Resharper caches:
https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206546989-ReSharper-stopped-working-for-a-single-specific-solution

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that there is an exception being thrown while it is being inserted and it fails to finish expanding the template. Can you run VS with `devenv.exe /ReSharper.Internal` and try again, please? Keep an eye out for a small popup in the bottom right of the window with details about an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think the shortcut  `Alt + Ins`  is assigned to wrong command. Follow below steps and verify whether the  keyboard shortcut is correct. Otherwise assign `Alt+Ins` to correct command.

-On the main menu, choose Tools | Options. Expand the Environment
    node, then click Keyboard.

[image]